# Transformer primary Voltage and emf relation

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

This is a conceptual query. So if possible kindly answer more conceptually.

Consider an ideal transformer. We have a input voltage Vp, and voltage in secondary coil as Vs.
now, we write emf equations,then divide and whatever...
then we get to result that- $\frac{Es}{Ep} = \frac{Ns}{Np}$
So the equation talks about ration of induced emfs. But what is the reason that we write Es=Vs and Vs=Ep and ultimately write $\frac{Vs}{Vp} = \frac{Ns}{Np}$
. Why would be induced emf same as applied voltage??
Also my textbook provides the reason that if it were not so current in primary would be infinite as we have assumed 0 resistance.